# Git and Atom Bomb

Tags: git, atom-editor

So I was trying to refresh by skills using local git last night around 4 AM. I opened Atom and git package dialog, initialized a new git repo in my project home directory. At this point some neurons misfired in my brain and I started clicking discard changes I saw in the git package dialog, I hadn't yet staged or committed any changes to repo. So now my entire project directory is empty, everything just blown away, about 1 years work. Anything I can do except cry?

Comment: Do you have a backup? If so, use it. If not, you may be able to use a data recovery tool. And, *always have a (tested) backup*. Also, commit constantly (i.e., more than once a year).

Comment: I guess if I had a backup I wouldn't be asking this question, which is really more of a confession. I even tried disk drill to see if I could recover from HD, there's nothing. Now I'm waiting for a response from firebase to see if I can recover from production hosting site. I think git could be a little more forgiving when deleting from working directory, I didn't even see a confirmation in atom.

Comment: If Atom didn't give a warning, I suggest [requesting that one be added](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/new/choose). If you can restore from production, then that is nice. If not, a professional data recovery company may be able to recover something. If you want that, I highly suggest shutting down the computer and not doing _anything_ on that drive. Including trying to recover data yourself.